# How to handle maximum file size Exception in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I am using Spring Boot v1.2.5 for creating a REST Application. While uploading images, I have a check for maximum file size , which is provided the property :

```
multipart.maxFileSize= 128KB
```

in application.properties. This facility is provided by Spring Boot itself. Now the check is working properly. The question is, how do I handle the exception and return a message to the user that he can understand ?

Update 1----------

I wrote a method within my Controller, where I intend to handle the MultipartException, using `@ExceptionHandler`. It does not seem to work.

This is my code :

```
@ExceptionHandler(MultipartException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.PAYLOAD_TOO_LARGE)
public ApplicationErrorDto handleMultipartException(MultipartException exception){
    ApplicationErrorDto applicationErrorDto =  new ApplicationErrorDto();
    applicationErrorDto.setMessage("File size exceeded");
    LOGGER.error("File size exceeded",exception);
    return applicationErrorDto;
}
```

Update 2----------

After @luboskrnac pointed it out, I have managed to come up with a solution. We can use `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` here to handle this particular case. I believe, we could also have used `DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver`, but `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` will allow us to return a `ResponseEntity`, as opposed to the former, the methods of which will return `ModelAndView`. I **have not** tried it though.

This is the final code that I'm using to handle the `MultipartException` :

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(CustomResponseEntityExceptionHandler.class);

@ExceptionHandler(MultipartException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.PAYLOAD_TOO_LARGE)
@ResponseBody
public ApplicationErrorDto handleMultipartException(MultipartException exception){
    ApplicationErrorDto applicationErrorDto =  new ApplicationErrorDto();
    applicationErrorDto.setMessage("File size exceeded");
    LOGGER.error("File size exceeded",exception);
    return applicationErrorDto;
}
}
```

I am using Swagger for developing/documenting REST Apis. This is the response upon uploading a file that exceeds the size.
[image]
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Spring Boot docs says](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-error-handling):

> You can also use regular Spring MVC features like `@ExceptionHandler`
>   methods and `@ControllerAdvice`. The `ErrorController` will then pick up
>   any unhandled exceptions.

As `MultipartException` seem to hapen before `@Controller/@ExceptionHandler/@ControllerAdvice` features comes into play, you should use `ErrorController` to handle it.

BTW, I found this [thread in the meantime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363705/handling-multipartexception-with-spring-boot-and-display-error-page). you may want to take a look.

Comment: I tried doing that. I tried handling the exception locally within my controller using ExceptionHandler,  instead of a global wrapper using ControllerAdvice, as instructed in the docs you had shared. I'm trying to handle MultipartException in the method. It does not seem to work.
@luboskrnac Please check the update 1.

Comment: I was wrong, before and corrected my answer. You want to use ErrorController.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I have updated my post with the final solution I'm using.

Comment: @luboskrnac what if I use @RestController? I don't want to return page - just object

Comment: @gstackoverflow AFAIK, it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @luboskrnac https://stackoverflow.com/a/47401986/2674303 - I found out the root cause. Tomcat  sucks