# How to add dynamic search by request param

Tags: java, spring, request, http-request-parameters

How should I correctly implement dynamic searching in my rest api request? My rest api is divided into Controller -> Service -> Repository.
I created GET request to get all drivers from database:

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<Set<DriverDTO>> getAll(@PageableDefault(value = 15) Pageable pageable) {

    Page<DriverEntity> driverEntities = driverService.getAll(pageable);
    Set<DriverDTO> driverDTOSet = modelMapperService.mapPageToSetOfEnteredClass(driverEntities, DriverDTO.class);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(driverDTOSet, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

and now I would like to add some searching parameters for example name, ageUpToX... so I added @RequestParams:

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<Set<DriverDTO>> getAll(@PageableDefault(value = 15) Pageable pageable,
                                             @RequestParam String name,
                                             @RequestParam int ageUpTo,
                                             @RequestParam int ageOver) {
    Page<DriverEntity> driverEntities = driverService.getAll(pageable);
    Set<DriverDTO> driverDTOSet = modelMapperService.mapPageToSetOfEnteredClass(driverEntities, DriverDTO.class);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(driverDTOSet, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Method getAll() from service looks like:

```
public Page<DriverEntity> getAll(Pageable pageable) {
    return driverEntityRepository.findAll(pageable);
}
```

So what is next? Should I add every requestParam to getAll method like:
getAll(String name, int ageUpTo,int ageOver) and checking in few if loops if field is empty/ != null? Or maybe by some switch?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate query parameters, you don't have to use if statement, that can be done in a more elegant way using annotations.

First, you will need to include following dependency in your `pom.xml` file

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

The `spring-boot-starter-validation` dependency will include all the jars needed for the validation of the request parameters.

So, if you want to validate the query parameter `ageUpTo` has minimum value 5, and maximum value of 7 you can use `@Validated` annotation with `@Min` and `@Max` annotation.
The `@Validated` annotation is used to specify the rest controller to be validated. The spring boot application validates all the method before it is called.
Here is example:

```
@Validated
 public RestController {

       @GetMapping
        public ResponseEntity<Set<DriverDTO>> getAll(@PageableDefault(value = 15) Pageable pageable,
                                                     @RequestParam String name,
                                                     @RequestParam @Min(5) @Max(7) int ageUpTo,
                                                     @RequestParam int ageOver) {
            Page<DriverEntity> driverEntities = driverService.getAll(pageable);
            Set<DriverDTO> driverDTOSet = modelMapperService.mapPageToSetOfEnteredClass(driverEntities, DriverDTO.class);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(driverDTOSet, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

If you want to validate that your request param `name` is not blank, you can use  `@NotBlank` annotation.

Also, you can customize the messages that will be displayed to the user in case the validation fails.

You can read more about it [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-validate-requestparam-pathvariable) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59422883/spring-boot-custom-validation-in-request-params)

If you want to search the database based on the given query parameters, you will have to declare a new method in the repository interface, which will perform the search based on the given parameters.  This implies that you will also have to declare a new method in the service that will call that method, similar to what you did earlier.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to add those parameters to your service method, otherwise to do is instead of sending one by one, you could send a Map to the service, where the key would be the column you need to filter, then you can iterate over the map and if the key/value are not null you can add this to a query Specification e.g:

```
Specification<MyDomain> querySpec = Specifications.where((root, query, cb) -> {
     Predicate p = null;
     //iterate over the map
     mapParam.forEach(k,v -> {
       if(k != null && v!= null) {
          p = cb.and(p, cb.equal(root.get(k), k));
       }
     })
     return p;
                });

// then use the specification
Page<MyDomain> pageResult = myRepo.findAll(querySpec, pageRequest);
```

beware that you need to perform some validations cuz `p` may be null,
another important thing is that your repository must extend from `JpaSpecificationExecutor`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Specifications in your spring repository,
where you need to extend JpaSpecificationExecutor, something like this

```
@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Post, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Post>{}
```

You have to make an Specification file where you will have your Search Specification there, something like below

```
public class PostSpecification implements Specification<Post> {

//.....other codes
//.....other codes

public static Specification<Post> bySearch(String search) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            if (search == null) {
                return criteriaBuilder.conjunction();
            }
            query.distinct(true);
            Predicate titlePredicate = criteriaBuilder.like(root.<String>get("title"), "%" + search + "%");
            Predicate contentPredicate = criteriaBuilder.like(root.<String>get("content"), "%" + search + "%");
            Predicate authorPredicate = criteriaBuilder.like(root.<String>get("author"), "%" + search + "%");

            Join<Post, Tag> postTagsTable = root.join("tags", JoinType.INNER);
            Predicate tagPredicate = criteriaBuilder.like(postTagsTable.get("name"), "%" + search + "%");

            return criteriaBuilder.or(titlePredicate, contentPredicate,
                    authorPredicate, tagPredicate);
        };
    }
}
```

Now you have to call findAll from your controller like this below

```
PostSpecification postSpecification = new PostSpecification();
Specification<Post> filteredSpecification = 
postSpecification.findByFilters(search, authorNames, tagNames);
            
posts = postRepository.findAll(filteredSpecification, pageable).getContent();
```