# Spring Boot: Custom exception or Validation for file uploading?

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, exception

For my file (csv) upload endpoint, I check the file type using a method in my CsvHelper class:

```
private static String[] TYPES =  {"text/csv", "application/vnd.ms-excel"};

public static boolean hasCsvFormat(MultipartFile file) {
    return Arrays.stream(TYPES).anyMatch(file.getContentType()::equals);
}
```

And call it from service as shown below:

```
public void create(MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
    if (!CsvHelper.hasCsvFormat(file)) {
        throw new NotValidFormatException(...);
    }
    // ...
}
```

I created a custom exception for this called `NotValidFormatException` using `@ControllerAdvice`, but I am not sure if it is the most proper way for this.

My questions:

**1.** Should I create custom exception or custom validator as mentioned on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40355743/file-upload-in-spring-boot-uploading-validation-and-exception-handling)? But as I have not a model field, I need to use `@Valid` on the request and not sure if I can use that approach to verify file type (by calling my `hasCsvFormat()` method.

**2.** I used [this](https://github.com/thombergs/code-examples/tree/master/spring-boot/exception-handling/src/main/java/io/reflectoring/exception/exception) approach for creating custom exception handling. If I wanted to use that approach for this scenario, should I create a separate class (e.g. `NotValidFormatException`) like `NoSuchElementFoundException` on that example? Or should I include a new exception method to the `GlobalExceptionHandler` class as a common exception type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your requirement, option number 2 is more suitable from my perspective.

You can create separate  class for `NotValidFormatException` , annotate with `ResponseStatus` of your need & extend it with `RuntimeException`.

Now, your `GlobalExceptionHandler`  is general purpose handler which perform actions once specific exception is thrown.

So you have to create method which should annotate with `@ExceptionHandler(NotValidFormatException.class)` in `GlobalExceptionHandler` .

Benefits of having separate class for `NotValidFormatException` is you can customize error message, can perform more operation within methods of that class.

If your requirement is minimal(like logging & returning response etc.) , then  I would suggest to have only single `ExceptionHandler` method in `GlobalExceptionHandler`  which will handle most of exceptions i.e. logging & returning response.

Comment: Perfect explanations! I am just wondering these issues, could you please clarify me about them? >>>

Comment: **1.** In this scene, when following second approach, I handle exceptions using `GlobalExceptionHandler` and if I want to customize any of them I add a separate exception class e.g. `NoSuchElementFoundException` and a handle method corresponding for this class e.g. `handleNoSuchElementFoundException`. IS that true?

Comment: **2.** For validation, I think the first approach is better, but not sure why people prefer the second one as I have seen for similar situations before. Of course it is also meaningful to throw `NotValidFormatException`, but for validation e.g. "valid e-mail", I would prefer validation instead of throving "not valid email exception". Am I wrong? Is it just related to preference or convention?

Comment: **3.** What about using [this](https://gist.github.com/susimsek/03b6a4d695b864dfe95d1b31959b3e53) approach? I also tried to use it, but cannot get custom message, instead I get general message. Is that approach also good for validating? And what is the problem with that approach?

Comment: @byte, your point 1 is correct.  Regarding validation, your validation will occur at service layer & it has nothing to do with how you throw your exception & handle.

Comment: Thanks for reply, regarding to 1 and 3 I could not understand. Any clarification pls?

Comment: By the way, I cannot vote up as I have not enough repo :( Any vote up pls?

Comment: For point 1:  think of `GlobalExceptionHandler` as just utility which has few handler methods for different kinds of exceptions.  Your different kind of exceptions are in their own separate class . For example you defined `NoSuchElementFoundException ` in its own separate class (NoSuchElementFoundException.java etc.).

Comment: But its handler method (i.e.  method which has `@ExceptionHandler(NoSuchElementFoundException.class)` annotation will be part of `GlobalExceptionHandler`. Your `NoSuchElementFoundException ` will have type of HTTP error code it will return  any default custom message it should throw when this exception occurs.

Comment: Your `GlobalExceptionHandler`'s handler method will just act when this exception occurs. When I say it `just act` it means this method can wrap this exception in separate response entity & return , printing logger about this exception etc. This can vary based on your requirement. 

Same thing happens if you introduce new exception type, put it in separate class, define handler in  `GlobalExceptionHandler`.

Comment: For point 3 : I am not sure what you mean by getting general message, as this code just sends HTTP status for `ConstraintViolationException` & `HTTP status + "Please select a file"` for `MultipartException` type.  So if you need custom exception , for example whatever you throws from your service, these handler methods has to be modify & read exceptions `getMessage()` first, for example `exception.getMessage()` will gives you message which you have provided while throwing exception .

Comment: So, in order to validate if the file has a valid type, should we use exception handler instead of custom validation? Why?

Comment: @byte, exception handler will get invoked only when your `controlleradvice` throws error.  Your custom validation method (which should be part of your your service class , should throw exception ; lets say your custom validation method should throw `NotValidFormatException`.  So you still need both custom validation logic & exception handler logic.

Comment: By the way now I just had received enough repo and vote up for your helps ;)

Comment: Hmmm, good explanations, thanks. In this case I see that both method are ok (using valid annotation and exceptionHandler) in order to check if the file has a valid type for example and the choice is depend on the preference of the developer. Is that true? And what is the pros and cons as far as you know for these 2 approaches? Thanks in advance

Comment: Any reply please?

Comment: I didn't get you what you mean by valid annotation.

Comment: I mean using custom valid annotation e.g. @ValidImage ?

Comment: I am not aware of that annotation

Comment: There is not such annotation, it is custom. Just think of custom annotation please :)

Comment: yeah, not sure about that idea, thank you .